# iOS App Suspended Too Quickly By The System

Tags: ios

In the previous versions of our app, the user can switch to another app, lock the screen or do whatever for 30 min, and comes back to our app to the same screen that the user left with. In other words, the app has been in background unsuspended running for this long. In a new update though, if the user goes to the Home Screen for even five minutes, the app is restarted when the user comes back, which means it's terminated by the system and thus restarted when opened. The memory occupation is the same as the previous versions, and we use the same device. Even with two version installed at the same time on the same phone open in background at the same time, the older one persists but the newer one gets terminated quickly. If there is memory pressure, shouldn't the app that uses the most be terminated first? I'm sure the newer one uses less memory. Could this be a Xcode bug, a settings/configuration I'm not aware of, or other cause?

Comment: most probably you have changed the logic in the app. App persists in the background if u have implemented 1. State Preservation  OR 2. Implemented background service. 

So please check your code. You can do compare very easily if you are using any repo say Git and you have code.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not guarantee a constant background time for any app (other than Apple apps obviously), IMHO your best bet is to implement state preservation and restoration as explained here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html